# Enum in abstract classes

Tags: java, enums, abstract

I am trying to figure out how to use enum in different classes extending a common abstract class.

Simple example:

---

Card Class

```
public class Card {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private String suit;

   public Card(String name, String value, String suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit= suit;
    }
}
```

---

Abstract DECK class

```
public abstract class Deck {
    private enum SUITS{

    }

    private enum VALUES{

    }
    private int cardNumber;
    private ArrayList<Card> cardList;

    public Deck(VALUES valori,SUITS semi){
        ArrayList<Card> clist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SUITS s: semi.values()){
            for (VALUES v: valori.values()){
                cardList.add(new Card(v.toString(),s.toString()));
            }
        }
        cardNumber = cardList.size();
    }
```

---

Class BriscolaDeck

```
public class CarteBriscolaDeck extends Deck {
   private enum SUITS{
        COPPE,
        DENARE,
        BASTONI,
        SPADE
    }

    private enum VALUES{
        ASSO,
        DUE,
        TRE,
        QUATTRO,
        CINQUE,
        SEI,
        SETTE,
        FANTE,
        CAVALLO,
        RE
    }

    public CarteBriscolaDeck(){
        super(VALUES,SUITS);
    }
}
```

---

Class PokerDeck

```
public class PokerDeck extends Deck {
   private enum SUITS{
       SPADES,
       HEARTS,
       DIAMONDS,
       CLUBS
   }

    private enum VALUES{
        ACE,
        TWO,
        THRRE,
        FOUR,
        FIVE,
        SIX,
        SEVEN,
        EIGHT,
        NINE,
        TEN,
        JACK,
        QUEEN,
        KING
    }

    public PokerDeck(){
        super(VALUES,SUITS);
    }
}
```

Am I doing it right? Is it possible to optimize?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: please let me know if my answer works for you; or if there is anything else you would be looking for; otherwise consider accepting the best fitting answer to indicate "you got what you need".

Answer (score 6):

You can’t declare an `enum` in a base class to be overridden by subclasses, as `enum`s are always implicitly `final`. Also, the subclass’ `enum`s can not extend an arbitrary type, they are always implicitly extending `java.lang.Enum`.

What you can do, is declare an `interface` in the base class which the subclass’ `enum` will implement. But since you didn’t specify any functionality in your enumerations that could be abstracted, there is no point in doing it (yet). The alternative is to specify type parameters for the base class which the subclasses will fill in with their actual types.

Another thing to fix, is to use the “suite” and “value” types instead of `String`s in your `Card` class, as using strings there destroys the entire advantage of use `enum`s.

E.g.

```
public final class Card<S,V> {
    final S suit;
    final V value;
    public Card(S suit, V value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return suit+" "+value;
    }
}
public class Deck<S extends Enum<S>,V extends Enum<V>> {
    protected final Set<S> allSuits;
    protected final Set<V> allValues;
    protected final List<Card<S,V>> allCards;

    public Deck(Class<S> suitType, Class<V> valueType) {
        Set<S> suits =EnumSet.allOf(suitType);
        Set<V> values=EnumSet.allOf(valueType);
        List<Card<S,V>> cardList=new ArrayList<>(suits.size()*values.size());
        for(S suite: suits){
            for(V value: values) {
                cardList.add(new Card<>(suite, value));
            }
        }
        allSuits =Collections.unmodifiableSet(suits);
        allValues=Collections.unmodifiableSet(values);
        allCards =Collections.unmodifiableList(cardList);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName()+allCards;
    }
}
public class PokerDeck extends Deck<PokerDeck.Suits,PokerDeck.Values> {
    enum Suits  { SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS }
    enum Values { ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN,
                  EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING }

    public PokerDeck(){
        super(Suits.class, Values.class);
    }
}
public class CarteBriscolaDeck
       extends Deck<CarteBriscolaDeck.Suits,CarteBriscolaDeck.Values> {
    enum Suits  { COPPE, DENARE, BASTONI, SPADE }
    enum Values { ASSO, DUE, TRE, QUATTRO, CINQUE, SEI, SETTE, FANTE, CAVALLO, RE }

    public CarteBriscolaDeck(){
        super(Suits.class, Values.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: just to be sure... you wrote:

    protected final Set<S> allSuits;
    protected final Set<V> allValues;

and after

    allSuits =Collections.unmodifiableSet(suits);
    allValues=Collections.unmodifiableSet(values);

is it a typo? because final means a costant.. right?

Comment: `final` fields can not be modified after the construction. But, of course, they have to be assigned once during the construction. Here, it happens at the end of the constructor, after the collections have been populated.

Comment: Check that the code in your IDE is *exactly* as posted here, besides the necessary `import` statements you have to add. This code is tested and the ability to assign a `final` field within the constructor is fundamental. It’s important that it has to be in the constructor and exactly once (per possible code path). And there *must not* be an initializer at the field itself.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that easy. You are declaring completely new types in your subclasses; so there is no implicit "overriding" as you would hope for.
You see, your base class constructor takes two enums of type Deck.SUITS, ... so passing in an enum of type Poker.SUITS can't work.

One way around that would be to use generics:

```
abstract class Deck<S extends Enum<S>, V extends Enum<V>> {
  abstract protected List<S> getSuiteEnums();
  abstract protected List<V> getValuesEnums();

  public Deck(){
    ArrayList<Card> clist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (S s: getSuiteEnums()){
    ...
}
```

and then, in your subclasses:

```
public class PokerDeck extends Deck<PokerDeck.POKERSUITES, PokerDeck.POKERVALUES> {
  enum POKERSUITS { SPADES, ..
  enum POKERVALUES { ...

  @Override 
  protected List<POKERSUITS> getSuiteEnum() { 
    return list with POKERSUITES.values());
```

Please note: this is more "pseudo-code" style; so forgive about typos and such. In order to make the PokerDeck.POKERSUITS work, that inner enum cant be private, too. And: I choose to use abstract methods here, because they help with the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

So, long story short: yes, this can be done with using Enums declared in child classes. But honestly; I do not see the added value of using enums there. You might as well have:

```
abstract protected List<String> getSuiteNames();
```

and implement that easily within each child class as:

```
return Arrays.asList("SPADES", "
```

Comment: You don't see the advantage of enums for representing a small number of predefined values? Comparisons are quicker, type checking is more tight. The real issue with the OP is that the `Card` fields are strings rather than instances of those Enums.

Comment: Probably one would have to sit down another 20 minutes to find an enum based solution that would allow to use them here; and also work for the subclassing thing. But honestly: I already spent quite some time here; without any "payoff" ... so, not sure, if that is going to happen soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is suitable.And I don't understand why you want to use Enum here.
A Collection can do same thing and more clearer for reader.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a constructor in your enum with a flag and pass the relevant values to the super method. filtering can be done using the SUIT_TYPS.ONE or SUIT_TYPES.TWO

```
public enum SUITS {

    COPPE(SUIT_TYPES.ONE.name()),
    DENARE(SUIT_TYPES.ONE.name()),
    BASTONI(SUIT_TYPES.ONE.name()),
    SPADE(SUIT_TYPES.ONE.name()),
    SPADES(SUIT_TYPES.TWO.name()),
    HEARTS(SUIT_TYPES.TWO.name()),
    DIAMONDS(SUIT_TYPES.TWO.name()),
    CLUBS(SUIT_TYPES.TWO.name());

    private final String type;

    SUITS(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}

enum SUIT_TYPES {
    ONE, TWO
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In Desk constructor:

```
public Desk(Object[] values, Object[] suits)
```

In sub classes:

```
public Subclass(){ 
    super(values.values(), suits.values()) 
}
```

Comment: I think you are either unfamiliar with the concept of enums, or your answer is an unclear attempt to show how to work with arrays instead of enums, in which case, you should improve it.